java.io.IOException: org.omg.CORBA.INITIALIZE: can't instantiate default ORB implementation com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBSingleton
I am migrating a java8 project to java17 and the project is using custom made library by the client which uses CORBA. (Client is not ready to migrate to java17). I am using Glassfish-corba-orb-4.2.1.jar. I am getting below error.

java.io.IOException: org.omg.CORBA.INITIALIZE: can't instantiate default ORB implementation com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBSingleton

Using eclipse i added below in the VM arguments as well but it did not help.
-Dorg.omg.CORBA.ORBSingletonClass=com.sun.corba.ee.impl.orb.ORBSingleton

Does this answer your question? Is there a replacement library for CORBA in JDK 11

i am getting same issue with this as well.

Could you resolve the issue?

In our eclipse rcp product third party plugins are used, which have the exact same issue.
Solution:
I added a plugin with following glassfish corba orb jars, added them to the classpath and exported all packages:

glassfish-corba-internal-api-4.2.5.jar
glassfish-corba-omgapi-4.2.5.jar
glassfish-corba-orb-4.2.5.jar
gmbal-4.0.3.jar management-api-3.2.3.jar
pfl-basic-4.1.2.jar
pfl-dynamic-4.1.2.jar
pfl-tf-4.1.2.jar

I got the jars with maven:
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.corba/glassfish-corba-orb -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.corba</groupId>
    <artifactId>glassfish-corba-orb</artifactId>
    <version>4.2.5</version>
</dependency>

